# React js : how to resolve multiple export?

Tags: reactjs, path, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

Hello i need to have a multiple export in react js but i have this error 
  Line 84:3:  Parsing error: Only one default export allowed per module.

this is my code :

```
  export default App;
  export default dashboardRoutes;
```

What i should to do to resolve this problems please !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export only one default component and the other like this:

```
export default MostImportantComponent
// other components
export {
    Component1,
    Component2,
    // ... etc
}
```

Notice that when you import the other components from other files you need to

```
import DefaultComponent from '...'
import { Component1, Component2 } from '...' // for other components
```

Comment: To note, if importing the default and named exports from within the same file, you can combine both styles like this:

`import DefaultComponent, { Component1 } from '...';`

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two types of exports.

1.Named Exports(Zero or more exports per module): This allows you to export multiple modules from a javascript file which is the case in your issue.

Solution to your case goes as follows 
*modules.js*

```
export {
App,
DashboardRoutes
};
```

*app.js*

```
import {App,DashboardRoutes} from './modules.js'
```

You can equally change the names of those modules in the import file as follows

2. Default Exports(One per module): This allows you to export only one module, which is the reason it showed you the error you have. This gives you the advantage of using a name of your choice in the file you import it from.

*modules.js page*

```
const module1=()=>console.log('module1');

export default module1
```

*app.js*
 
The page that is using the modules

```
import MyModule from './modules.js'
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 0):

you can use named export or one as default and other as named export.

Comment: YouTube video can be deleted, please edit your answer for better answer

Comment: Thank's sir, for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Define functions

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
function sub(a, b) {
  return a - b
}
function mul(a, b) {
  return a * b
}
```

Define export
`export { sum, sub, mul }`

Import functions you need
`import { sum, sub } from 'myfile'`
or all the functions
`import * as myfunctions from 'myfile'`

and call as
`sum(1+1)` or `myfunctions.sum(1+1)`

src: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-export-multiple-functions-javascript/